# Flush Mount Ceiling/Wall Speakers

Tags: home-theater

I am building a house.  Right now I am at the stage where there is no drywall or insulation, we just got dried in. We just installed the electrical.  I got the idea that I'd like to install something now that would allow me to hang in the wall and ceiling speakers.

I am using an older system that I already have.  it is a Sony STR-K790 5.1 Surround Sound.  The speakers are rectangular, but I've mounted these in the ceiling in a rental home in the past that was already wired for surround sound and the round ones work just fine.  I'd also like for these to be flush mounted.

Is there something out there designed for flush mounting speakers in the ceiling before drywall is installed?

One other note, I will be storing all of my equipment in a media closet about 12 ft from where the tv is mounted so I will be running the wires out of the components into the ceiling of the closet and out to the speakers.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I've installed plugs into the closet already.  Just need to work out running HDMI cables, RCA cables etc. through the wall to the closet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the speakers, the ceiling mount speakers I have used have their own "can" and just need a hole in the drywall and wires. They are not designed to be trapped by the drywall, they are designed to be installed into it and can be removed from it when/if desired. You can get separate empty cans and speakers to put in them if desired - any AV supply place, ceiling mount speaker cans...

For the wires: Conduit. This stuff changes rapidly compared to other building systems. So, place conduit and easily update it when everything changes again (enough that you choose to upgrade).

Otherwise in 10 years you'll have the equivalent of a VGA cable and quadrophonic speaker cables stuck in the wall today - antiquated, though you might be able to kludge some use out of them.

While you are at *dried in but no drywall*, think about networking, and wiring wireless access points (which work best if they are wired and the things that connect to them can see them without going though walls.) Easy now, hard later. Nobody remembers to put networking in the ceilings, but that's where you want it to make your portable devices work well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is very helpful!

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the wireless access point connects via ethernet?  so I should just run an ethernet cable from the ceiling in my living room to the media closet?

Comment: Yes, they use ethernet, and usually power over ethernet so they just need an ethernet cable. However, that is also a place to consider using conduit to face the fact that the ethernet cable of 20 years ago and the ethernet cable of today are not quite the same animal, so logically it might be the case that in 10 or 20 years you'd want the ability to change it out for whatever is current then. But you don't have to do that.

Comment: May be helpful (to non-networking types) what types of ethernet cables are acceptable today (in case conduit isn't an option, or not desired), and move the "conduit" comment into the networking portion of your answer also.